# Node.js. Missing timeMin parameter on freebusy query. Google calendar API

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to use the google-api-nodejs-client in Node.js. I have a problem with the format of the `timeMin` parameter in the `freebusy` query. According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query), the value should be timedate in ISO format. I tried that but I got an error. In the `event.list` method the ISO format string works fine.

Query `freebusy` code:

```
function freeBusyStatus (auth, calendarId) {
    const startDate = new Date('20 February 2018 12:00').toISOString()
    const endDate = new Date('20 February 2018 13:00').toISOString()
    const check = {
        auth: auth,
        // timeMin: '2018-02-20T12:00:00+03:00', //not working with same format too
        timeMin: new Date('20 February 2018 12:00'),
        timeMax: endDate,
        items: [{id: calendarId}]
    }
    calendar.freebusy.query (check, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log ('error: ' + err)
        } else {
            ..some code..
        }
    })
}
```

And code `events.list` with dates in the ISO format. This code works:

```
function listEvents(auth, calendarId) {
    const eventList = {
        auth: auth,
        calendarId: calendarId,
        timeMin: new Date('20 February 2018 12:00').toISOString(),
        maxResults: 10,
        singleEvents: true,
        orderBy: 'startTime'
    }
    calendar.events.list(eventList, function(err, response) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    const events = response.data.items
        if (events.length != 0) { 
            ..some code..
        }
    })
}
```

I think that the problem is with the date format. When I try to send a request with dates like `2018-02-20` (without time), the response has the same error `Error: Missing timeMin parameter.`

What am I doing wrong? Authorization is done with JWT.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Done! My mistake was with structure of request

```
function freeBusyStatus (auth, calendarId) {
    const check = {
        auth: auth,
        resource: {
            timeMin: startDate,
            timeMax: endDate,
            items: [{id: calendarId}]
        }
    }
    const startDate = new Date('20 February 2018 12:00').toISOString()
    const endDate = new Date('20 February 2018 13:00').toISOString()
    calendar.freebusy.query (check, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log ('error: ' + err)
        } else {
            ..some code..
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: so the official documentation was, and is still, just plain wrong? I had the exact same issues just now. How did you figure this out? Are there docs I'm missing?

Comment: Its 2021 and its still not fixed... I wasted so much time :( Thanks kind stranger!